# Latent heat of water at triple point

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, phase-diagram

My class textbook states that the latent heat at triple point of water is zero. When i tried to look up there was less to no information about this fact. Can anyone give any plausible explanation for why this could be correct or may provide arguments as well for why this could be a false statement?

Is it anything to do with the fact that the three states of matter are co-existing with each other? Even during phenomenon like boiling and freezing two states of matter as in liquid/vapour; solid/liquid co-exist together but they still consume the heat and we call this the latent heat or hidden heat.
I also thought maybe at such temp and pressure the value of latent heat becomes negligible but i am not able to find any value of latent heats at such temp or pressures.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Latent heat for which transition? The solid-liquid the liquid-vapor or the solid-vapor? In any case, I have a hard time understanding the statement about zero latent heat. Latent heat is directly proportional to the slope of the P-T coexistence line. Zero latent heat would imply a zero slope. If you look at the water phase diagram ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Phase_diagram_of_water.svg ), you may see that this is not the case.

Comment: Well they havent't mentioned which latent heat. Is zero latent heat possible anywhere?

Comment: Can you please quote the exact wording from your book?

Comment: @MandavaKarthikeya, whichever latent heat you are talking about, it is NOT zero at the triple point.  Either the text book wording is incorrect or you have misinterpreted something in that book.

Answer (score 1):

The phase diagram of water is like this (the image comes from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram) )

[image]

The only possibility for zero latent heat with a non-zero slope of the coexistence curve would be if there was the same density for the solid and liquid phases. This is not the case, since the triple point density of ice is about $917$ and that of the corresponding liquid is about $999.8$  $kg/m^3$.